# Latex beamer. Only the first two slides have slide number with this particular them: How to change that?

Tags: beamer

You can see below my .tex script and .sty theme. When using this theme, only the first two slides have slide numbers, while when removing this theme all the slides have numbers. I know that I have to change something in the .sty theme, but after a few attempts, I have not found the solution.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usetheme{theme1}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref} % allows clickable urls
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings} % show code

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newlength\yearposx
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\definecolor{lightgrey}{RGB}{245,245,245}

% slide numbering
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

% define title page

% begin document
\begin{document}


    

\frame{
    \frametitle{a}
}

\frame{
    \frametitle{a}
}

\frame{
    \frametitle{a}
}

\frame{
    \frametitle{a}
}
\end{document}
```

Theme theme1:

```
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\mode<presentation>

\newdimen\beamer@ubBorderHeight
\newdimen\beamer@ubTitleHeight
\newdimen\beamer@ubFooterHeight
\newdimen\beamer@ubOverlap

\beamer@ubOverlap=0.2pt
\beamer@ubBorderHeight=0.015\paperheight
\beamer@ubTitleHeight=0.125\paperheight
\beamer@ubFooterHeight=0.032\paperheight

\definecolor{ubRed}{HTML}{E6002E}
\definecolor{ubGrey}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=ubRed}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=ubRed}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=ubRed}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{date in title page}{fg=black}

% set fonts
\RequirePackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi



\setbeamerfont*{structure}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{title}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=ubRed}
\setbeamerfont*{subtitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamerfont*{author}{size*={10}{12},series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{institute}{size*={10}{12}}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=ubRed}
\setbeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{framesubtitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont*{date}{size*={8}{10}}
\setbeamerfont*{headline}{size*={8}{10}}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{uni bern}{%
  % list trick from https://texfaq.org/FAQ-chngmargonfly
  \begin{list}{}{
  \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}}
  \item[]
  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  {\usebeamerfont*{title}\color{ubRed}\inserttitle\par} % no idea why usebeamercolor{title} does not work here
  {\usebeamerfont*{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}
  \vspace{\stretch{1}}
  {\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par}
  {\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par}
  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  \end{list}
%  \end{minipage}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{background canvas}{uni bern}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth+10pt}
   \setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
   \setlength{\lineskip}{-\beamer@ubOverlap}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
   \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{1}{}{}

   \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{2}{
        \ifdefempty{\insertframesubtitle}{
          \rule{0pt}{6ex+\beamer@ubTitleHeight}\\
          \color{ubGrey}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight-\beamer@ubTitleHeight-\beamer@ubFooterHeight-6ex}
        }{
          \rule{0pt}{6ex+2\beamer@ubTitleHeight}\\          
          \color{ubGrey}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight-2\beamer@ubTitleHeight-\beamer@ubFooterHeight-6ex}   
        }
   }{}
  \end{minipage}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{uni bern}{% 
    \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{2}{
      \vspace{3.5ex}
      \hspace{4.5ex}\inserttitle
    }{}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{uni bern}{
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
\vspace{0.5ex}
\raggedright
\vspace{3.5ex}
{\insertframetitle\par}
{\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor*{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}
\end{minipage}
}


% set bullets

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{uni bern}{$\bullet$}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subitem}{uni bern}{$\bullet$}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=4ex}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=4ex}



\mode<all>
```

Comment: Although `navigation symbols` are not printed at all, you use this template to print frame numbers and (I don't know where nor why) `navigation symbols` disappear from frame 3 and your frame numbers also disappear. I'd suggest to use `footline` template to print frame numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Urg, this theme does a lot of very bad things.

The worst is the headline. It's height changes not only  throughout the presentation without recalculating the frame geometry, but also uses content like `\inserttitle` which can vary in height, e.g. depending if the title does have descenders like the letter `g` or might even be empty as in your example.

Beamer can't adept the rest of the frame to these changes because the frame geometry is never recalculated. As a result, the navigation symbols sometimes will end up outside the visible area of the page.

This specific problem can be avoided by placing the pagenumber in the template which is made for this purpose: the `footline`, nevertheless all the other issues should be fixed as well before using this template.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\mode<presentation>

\newdimen\beamer@ubBorderHeight
\newdimen\beamer@ubTitleHeight
\newdimen\beamer@ubFooterHeight
\newdimen\beamer@ubOverlap

\beamer@ubOverlap=0.2pt
\beamer@ubBorderHeight=0.015\paperheight
\beamer@ubTitleHeight=0.125\paperheight
\beamer@ubFooterHeight=0.032\paperheight

\definecolor{ubRed}{HTML}{E6002E}
\definecolor{ubGrey}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=ubRed}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=ubRed}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=ubRed}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{date in title page}{fg=black}

% set fonts
\RequirePackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi



\setbeamerfont*{structure}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{title}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=ubRed}
\setbeamerfont*{subtitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamerfont*{author}{size*={10}{12},series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{institute}{size*={10}{12}}
\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=ubRed}
\setbeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{size*={18}{22}}
\setbeamercolor*{framesubtitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont*{date}{size*={8}{10}}
\setbeamerfont*{headline}{size*={8}{10}}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{uni bern}{%
  % list trick from https://texfaq.org/FAQ-chngmargonfly
  \begin{list}{}{
  \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\rightmargin}{0pt}}
  \item[]
  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  {\usebeamerfont*{title}\color{ubRed}\inserttitle\par} % no idea why usebeamercolor{title} does not work here
  {\usebeamerfont*{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}
  \vspace{\stretch{1}}
  {\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par}
  {\usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par}
  \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
  \end{list}
%  \end{minipage}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{background canvas}{uni bern}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\paperwidth+10pt}
   \setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}
   \setlength{\lineskip}{-\beamer@ubOverlap}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
   \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{1}{}{}

   \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{2}{
        \ifdefempty{\insertframesubtitle}{
          \rule{0pt}{6ex+\beamer@ubTitleHeight}\\
          \color{ubGrey}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight-\beamer@ubTitleHeight-\beamer@ubFooterHeight-6ex}
        }{
          \rule{0pt}{6ex+2\beamer@ubTitleHeight}\\          
          \color{ubGrey}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight-2\beamer@ubTitleHeight-\beamer@ubFooterHeight-6ex}   
        }
   }{}
  \end{minipage}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{uni bern}{% 
    \ifnumgreater{\c@framenumber}{2}{
      \vspace{3.5ex}
      \hspace{4.5ex}\inserttitle
      \vspace{-4.5ex}
    }{}
}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{uni bern}{
\begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
\vspace{0.5ex}
\raggedright
\vspace{3.5ex}
{\insertframetitle\par}
{\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor*{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}
\end{minipage}
}


% set bullets

\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{uni bern}{$\bullet$}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subitem}{uni bern}{$\bullet$}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=4ex}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=4ex}



\mode<all>

\makeatother


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref} % allows clickable urls
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings} % show code

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newlength\yearposx
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\definecolor{lightgrey}{RGB}{245,245,245}

% slide numbering
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \hfill
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}


% define title page
\title{text}
% begin document
\begin{document}


    

\frame{
    \frametitle{a}
}

\frame{
    \frametitle{a}
}

\frame{
    \frametitle{a}
}

\frame{
    \frametitle{a}
}
\end{document}
```